# How to use new version of fontawesome in liferay

Tags: css, liferay, liferay-6, font-awesome, liferay-theme

I am using liferay 6.2 and i want to use the Fontawesome 4.2.0 in the new theme in liferay.
i have tried to replace the exsisting fontawesome ttf file with the new one , but it didn't help. How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Replacing only the ttf is not enough.
You have to build a new theme and rewrite the files under \css\aui\alloy-font-awesome\scss through _diffs folder.
It's hard to do but it's possible.